# How to rewrite the response body and empty the original content in the middleware?

Tags: go, middleware, go-gin

Hope to output `replace data`, but output `origin data`+`replace data` or no output after trying

I want to rewrite response body in middleware,Only want to output `replace data`,Refer to [How to rewrite response body in middleware?](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/3384), modify my code as
Requests are routed to

```
    ToolsGroup := Router.Group("")
    ToolsGroup .Use(middleware.ToolsGroupPermission())
    {
        ToolsGroup .GET("/ptr", func(c *gin.Context) {
            c.Data(http.StatusOK, "text/plain", []byte("orign data"))
        })
    }
```

Middleware is

```
package middleware

import (
    "bytes"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func ToolsGroupPermission() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        wb := &toolBodyWriter{
            body:           &bytes.Buffer{},
            ResponseWriter: c.Writer,
        }
        c.Writer = wb

        c.Next()

        wb.body.Reset()
        wb.Write([]byte("replace data"))
        //c.Data(http.StatusOK, "text/plain", []byte("replace data"))
    }
}

type toolBodyWriter struct {
    gin.ResponseWriter
    body *bytes.Buffer
}

func (r toolBodyWriter) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    return r.body.Write(b)
}
```

When the above code is modified, all `[] bytes` cannot be output.
But the reference is changed to [how do i get response body in after router middleware?](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/1363)
 when commenting:

```
func (r toolBodyWriter) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    r.body.Write(b)
    return r.ResponseWriter.Write(b)
}
```

Will output `origin data`+`replace data` at the same time. But the requirement is to output `replace data`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot take back what you have written to r.ResponseWriter. Don't call ResponseWriter.Write before you know what you want to send to the client.

ToolsGroupPermission should either copy from the buffer to c.Writer, or call c.Data. There is no reason to even have the toolBodyWriter type; other handlers shouldn't have access to the original ResponseWriter if you plan to replace the response:

```
func ToolsGroupPermission() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
        rw := c.Writer        
        c.Writer = buf

        c.Next()

        var replaceResponse bool

        if replaceResponse {
            c.Data(http.StatusOK, "text/plain", []byte("replace data"))
        } else {
            // TODO: Copy header and status code somehow. I'm not familiar enough with gin to know how to do that nicely.
            io.Copy(rw, buf)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion, but still the same result.The API method will directly call c.Data for output, and it is impossible to control not to call gin.ResponseWriter. But write this middleware to replace the corresponding output. So need to reset the ResponseWriter to output the converted content

Comment: Thank you again for your help, according to your tips, I temporarily modified the code to l two schemes and both can be implemented using gin middleware. code show as below:

Answer (score 0):

```
package middleware

import (
    "bytes"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func ToolsGroupPermission() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        wb := &toolBodyWriter{
            body:           &bytes.Buffer{},
            ResponseWriter: c.Writer,
        }
        c.Writer = wb

        c.Next()

        originBytes := wb.body
        fmt.Printf("%s", originBytes)
        // clear Origin Buffer
        wb.body = &bytes.Buffer{}
        wb.Write([]byte("replace data"))
        wb.ResponseWriter.Write(wb.body.Bytes())
        //c.Data(http.StatusOK, "text/plain", []byte("replace data"))
    }
}

type toolBodyWriter struct {
    gin.ResponseWriter
    body *bytes.Buffer
}

func (r toolBodyWriter) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    return r.body.Write(b)
}
```

Or

```
package middleware

import (
    "bytes"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func ToolsGroupPermission() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        wb := &toolBodyWriter{
            body:           &bytes.Buffer{},
            ResponseWriter: c.Writer,
            status:         Origin,
        }
        c.Writer = wb

        c.Next()
        wb.status = Replace
        originBytes := wb.body
        fmt.Printf("%s", originBytes)
        // clear Origin Buffer
        wb.body = &bytes.Buffer{}
        wb.Write([]byte("replace data"))
        //c.Data(http.StatusOK, "text/plain", []byte("replace data"))
    }
}

type toolBodyWriter struct {
    gin.ResponseWriter
    body *bytes.Buffer
    status byte
}
const (
    Origin  byte = 0x0
    Replace      = 0x1
)

func (r toolBodyWriter) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    if r.status == 0x1 {
        r.body.Write(b)
        return r.ResponseWriter.Write(b)
    } else {
        return r.body.Write(b) //r.ResponseWriter.Write(b)
    }
}
```